# logging activity to database yii framework

Tags: php, logging, yii

I'm using yii framework and I want to make an activity logging for every action that user do in my web. All of their activity will be saved to a table in database.

The things that will be recorded are:

- user ID
- table name (inserted, deleted, edited item)
- time_action
- activity (what did they do. ex: created project_name)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but is it like when a user deletes some item; then entry should be logged in database for that user?
If yes, then you can create a common class and a static method in it like,

```
yourCommonClass::setActivityLog(user_id,activity_msg,time);
```

and put this code in every action that you have written. ex. actionUpdate, actionDelete.

- you can get the user_id from `Yii::app()->user->id`
- put you custom activity message like "User #user_id created new item" etc.
- time you can get it while saving into database.

By the way, create a table and model for the same like ActivityLog. ;)
This is what I did in my project.

Comment: thanks for replying.. i got my own solution. its almost the same with your solution. by adding in every action in my controller and give some hardcode + get variable that been input by user. thanks to you :)